# Route + Paginação - Cake 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2

estou com uma dúvida "clássica" sobre paginação. Fiz conforme abaixo, tudo funcionou normalmente, só que não consegui montar a route para a paginação ficar como eu quero.

Tentei isso:

- Controller

  ```
  class NoticiasController extends AppController {

               /**
              * Lista as notícias utilizando paginação
              */

              public function lista($page = 1) {

                                   $options = array(

                                                       'fields' => array('Noticia.titulo', 'Noticia.resumo'),

                                                       'conditions' => array('Noticia.active' => true),


                                                       'page' => $page,

                                                       'order' => array('Noticia.created' => 'DESC'),

                                                       'limit' => 10

                                   );

                                   $this->paginate = $options;

                                   // Roda a consulta, já trazendo os resultados paginados

                                   $noticias = $this->paginate('Noticia');

                                   // Envia os dados pra view

                                   $this->set('noticias', $noticias);

                                   debug($page);

              }


  }
  ```
- View

  ```
   <article>

   <?php foreach($noticias AS $data): ?>

              <h1><?php echo $data['Noticia']['titulo'] ?></h1>

              <p><?php echo $data['Noticia']['resumo'] ?></p>

   <?php endforeach; ?>

   </article>

  <?php

  echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Mais novas', null, null, array('class' => 'desabilitado'));

  echo $this->Paginator->numbers();

  echo $this->Paginator->next('Mais antigas »', null, null, array('class' => 'desabilitado'));

  ?>
  ```
- Routes

  ```
  Router::connect('/noticias', array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'listar')); // pagina 1
  Router::connect('/noticias/:page', array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'listar'), array('pass' => array('page'))); // pagina 2 em diante
  ```

Nesse caso os links da página site.com.br/noticias ficam corretos (site.com.br/noticias/2 para a página 2, site.com.br/noticias/3 para a página 3, etc). Mas ao abrir as páginas 2, 3, 4, etc, mostra sempre o resultado da página 1.

Dei um `debug($page)` no controller, mas não sei se coloquei no local correto.

Ali sempre dá (int) 1, ou seja, parece que o valor `$page` não é levado para as páginas.

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho a certeza, mas experimenta retirar este route

```
Router::connect('/noticias/:page', array('controller' => 'noticias', 'action' => 'listar'), array('pass' => array('page')));
```

e já deves conseguir receber o parametro page correctamente